# Angular 8 doesn't work correctly in Firefox

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox, angular-ui-router, styling

I found an error when my Angular project was run on Firefox but incognito Firefox ran smoothly, for Chrome it also ran smoothly,
when I run it in Firefox an error appears like this:

[image: figure]

If you move from the login page to the dashboard the error doesn't exist.
This is an illustration of moving the login page to the dashboard.
There is no error in the Firefox console. Whereas if I refresh the problem is resolved.

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some detail. If you want help with your code, it's impossible for anyone to help you if you don't show the code you want help with. In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76900317/edit) and add some code to your question.

Comment: sorry, I can't display the code because I don't know where the error is, but to reproduce it when I log in and switch pages to the dashboard for the page switching animation it gets stuck @ChrisBarr

Comment: Well it's impossible for anyone to help you then. You have the code, but we don't, so how can we possibly know what the problem is if we don't even have the code? Screenshots here show the symptoms, not the cause of the problem.

Comment: I dont get your issue. are the texts missing?

Comment: I've included screenshots in the question

Comment: my code runs well in chrome and firefox incognito, but not in firefox, i run it locally @Hugo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When you feel like it, try creating a new, blank Angular project, and add to it until it starts misbehaving in Firefox in the same way, but not in Chrome. Then, provide that code. This is the process of creating a [mre], which are pretty much required when the problem arises from code running differently in one browser than in another. This question is likely to be closed until that task is complete.